# Delete Multiselected Row From Listbox loaded With Textbox Values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a multi selected Listbox3 that i add items to via textboxes. What i want to do is to multi-select the items added and delete them at a goal. I searched for the following code but it only deletes one row at a time.

```
'With Me.ListBox3
        If .ListIndex <> -1 Then
            If MsgBox("Delete current item?" & vbCrLf & .Value, vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "Delete entry") = vbYes Then
                .RemoveItem (.ListIndex)
            End If
        End If
    End With
```

'
Would be grateful if i can get help on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**How to delete multiselect items in a ListBox?**

First create a Userform named `Userform1` , two CommandButtons `CommandButton1` caption `Delete` and `CommandButton2` caption `Cancel` and a ListBox `ListBox1` with property `MultiSelect = 2`.

Put this code into the userform's code block.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

For i = Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
If Me.ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then Me.ListBox1.RemoveItem i
Next i
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Me.Hide
End Sub
```

This code in a **Module**

```
Sub delete_lines_demo()

'Add content to the listbox
list_range = Sheet12.Range("H26:H29")   'this is the range of the displayed data.
UserForm1.ListBox1.List = list_range
UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```